# vue+webpack, system told me "Module build failed: TypeError: this._init is not a function"

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js

I don't know how to fix it, I have been search too many informations, all of people told me I don't install npm module, but my 'package.json' file has already installed them.

I have installed all npm module

```
dependencies": {
"babel-core": "^6.22.1",
"babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
"babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
"babel-runtime": "^6.22.0",
"css-loader": "^0.26.1",
"style-loader": "^0.13.1",
"vue": "^2.1.10",
"vue-hot-reload-api": "^2.0.8",
"vue-html-loader": "^1.2.3",
"vue-loader": "^10.3.0",
"vue-template-compiler": "^2.1.10",
"webpack": "^2.2.1",
"webpack-dev-server": "^2.3.0"}
```

other files 
webpack.config.js

```
module.exports={
entry:'./main.js',

output:{
    path:__dirname,
    filename:'build.js'
},

module:{
    loaders:[
        {test:/\.vue$/, loader:'vue'},
        {test:/\.js$/, loader:'babel-loader', exclude:/node_modules/}
    ]
}};
```

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

new Vue({
    el:'body',
    components:{
        app:App
    }
});
```

App.vue

```
<template>
    <h1>welcome Vue</h1>
</template>

<script type="text/javascript"></script>

<style type="text/css"></style>
```

and the final file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
    <app></app>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

when I start webpack-dev-server, shell told me 
[TypeError: this._init is not a function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLYo8.jpg)

(ps : my English is not good, so....)

I have solved this problem, In 'webpack.config.js' file

```
{test:/\.vue$/, loader:'vue'}
```

change to

{test:/.vue$/, loader:'vue-loader'}

Because I use vue 2.0 version.

Comment: Which version of Vue are you using? In Vue 2 you can't target `html` or `body` tags in `el` property.

Comment: I use Vue 2, but  when i changed el to '#xxx', this error still exitst

Comment: Into Webpack 2 omitting word loader when initializing some loader is not allowed.So you have explicitly define full name of loader including `-loader`, such as `babel-loader`, `vue-loader`, `file-loader` etc...

Answer (score 0):

The line in `webpack.config.js` should be full name:

```js
{test:/\.vue$/, loader:'vue-loader'},
```